# How to get clock system of a device in C#? (12-hour or 24-hour)

Tags: c#, datetime, localization

I want to show a date to the users in my app. Some users may use 12-hour system, some may use 24-hour system. How can I get if the user's system is using 12-hour system or 24-hour system, so that I can print a date depending on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net gets `DateTime` formats directly from OS. You can use `ToShortTimeString()` or `ToLongTimeString()` methods to get representation of user.

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```